# Проблема с .htaccess (Options -Indexes)

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache2

Структура проекта:

```
/var/www/html/mvc
                 app/
                 public/index.php
                 .htaccess
```

Внутри `.htaccess`: `Options -Indexes`, но доступ к `app/` все равно есть. В чем может быть проблема?
`Xenial 16.04`

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
                            /000-default-le-ssl.conf
                            /000-default.conf
                            /default-ssl.conf
```

`000-default-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/путь к .pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/путь к private .pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerName домен_я_припрятал
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

`000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

`default-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/путь к .pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/путь к .key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

`apache2.conf`

```
...
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: service apache2 reload?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич пробовал, не помогло

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite ?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич тоже нет( сейчас в конфигах буду смотреть

Comment: А можно sites-available в студию? :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич обновил вопрос

Comment: Что означает фраза «доступ к app/ все равно есть»?

Comment: что то я не вижу RewriteEngine On

Comment: @andreymal имел ввиду доступ извне (т. е. по ссылке mydomain/mvc/app открывается структура папки, вместо желанной 403 Forbidden)

Comment: Тут случайно AllowOverride не забыт?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич @andreynal в `000-default.conf`? Сейчас пробую

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` в `000-default.conf` не помог, `AllowOverride All` - ошибка при поптыке `service apache2 restart` `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

Comment: Решил частично вопрос с [овтета](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445273/6478676), но для папок, к примеру, с файлами только `.css` тоже доступ будет запрещен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас стоит `AllowOverride None` то apache не будет считывать файл .htaccess

Отредактируйте 
`000-default.conf` так:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

делаем `service apache2 reload` и 
тогда ваш .htaccess будет работать